# Does one make bracha "borei minei besamim" on incense or spice smoke?

Tags: halacha, blessing, smell, fire-burning

I know that when you smell "raw" spices, you say "borei minei besamim". Can you make this bracha on the smokey smell when these spices are being burned? Some examples:

- If you burn an incense stick where the stick is made from a combo of
  cinnamon, lavender and other spices.
- If you use mesquite wood chips in your barbecue, can you make the
  bracha when the wood is burning?
- Similarly, if you put spices on the meat and the spicy smoke comes
  through the meat, should you make the bracha?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without addressing your specific examples, the answer is:

Yes, you can say a bracha on burning incense, but only once the pillar of smoke rises up from the burnt spices (Shulchan Arukh OC 216:12). You say whatever blessing you would have said on the spices themselves (ibid. :13).