# Berachot over flavored vaping/e cigarettes

Tags: halacha, blessing, technology, contemporary-halacha, tobacco-cig-smoking

Does Halacha require making a beracha after flavored vaping? To my understanding, the  consensus practice  is there is none over smoking. But if a Jew vapes a flavored e cigarette, do they recite a Berakha on the taste or smell?

Or no, is this not considered something  that requires a blessing. Sources for the answer to this question please.

Comment: As far as I know vaping is assur. Thus this question is the same as does a Jew make a bracha on non kosher food

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101632/do-i-make-bracha-on-smelling-vapor-from-herbs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The משנה ברורה in סימן רי ס״ק י״ז addresses the question of making a bracha before smoking pipe tobacco and states that there is no bracha recited.

As far as smell is concerned, the ערוך השולחן ס׳ רטז ס׳ ד states that there is no bracha on the smell of tobacco as that is not the persons intention when smoking it. The logic in both instances would seem to apply to vaped as well. Additionally, vape scent produced from vape smoke is generally synthetic(meaning not real mango or cherry etc.) and thus according to some poskim would not get a bracha on the smell.